# Will CouchDB support HTTP2?

Tags: rest, http, erlang, couchdb, http2

CouchDB API's are accessible via HTTP. Designs and document CRUD operations can be achieved via simple requests.

However, the concern people raise about performance may be mitigated by adopting the HTTP2 protocol.

Am I way out line for thinking this?

Does anyone know if there are thoughts or direction for this initiative?

Comment: It would probably be an idea worth exploring, however you would probably be better off bringing this idea up in the mailing lists for CouchDB and MochiWeb.

Comment: In a recent Couch discussion there was mention of using a project called Cowboy as the underbelly for serving our HTTP needs.